# Flow generics with React render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, types, flowtype

I have a component that receives the prop `items`, defined as an array of any type. It loops over this array can calls the prop `render` on each item in the array:

```
type ResultCardsProps = {
  items: *[],
  render: * => Node,
};

const ResultCards = ({ items, render, ...props }: ResultCardsProps) => (
  <div {...props}>
    {items.map(render)}
  </div>
);
```

Here's an example of how I'd use this component:

```
type Sport = { id: number, name: string };
type Props = { sports: Sport[] };

const SportsCards = ({ sports }: Props) => (
  <ResultCards
     items={sports}
     render={sport => <div>{sport.name}</div>} // Flow does not know the type for `sport` at this point
  />
);
```

Is there a way to make Flow understand the type being passed to the `render` function in the `SportsCard` component? It *does* work if the components are in the same file, but stops working when the are put in different files. I tried using generics for `ResultCardsProps`, but it didn't make a difference:

```
type ResultCardsProps<T> = {
  items: T[],
  render: T => Node,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there -- you just need to pass the generic type through the `ResultCards` component signature as well:

```
const ResultCards = <T>({ items, render, ...props }: ResultCardsProps<T>) => (
  <div {...props}>
    {items.map(render)}
  </div>
);

const SportsCards = ({ sports }: Props) => (
  <ResultCards
    items={sports}
    render={sport => (
      <div>
        {sport.name}
        <div>{sport.foo}</div>
      </div>
    )}
  />
);

// The above generates this Flow error:
// ^ Cannot get `sport.foo` because property `foo` is missing in `Sport` [1].
```

[(Flow REPL)](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeMCeYScAchACZIC+cAZlBCHAORSobMDcAUNwUYiQBnAK4AbGAGEUUckIAKDMEIA8AFQB8cALy5ucOMBhIQQgFxw1AbQC6mfXDYA7SlAtqdWspW5Ue3NAgnIXhkUQlpWSEdOHUNAAocQ2NTbGdXbAA6bLAlaKoLMPEpGTlFCGU4gEpPOHiHFXJgADdcbMzciqEqDQcDHCMTIUyQFDB49KQoKqoGgHom5t6q-35iAGVIWBik4HILJxEQACMp7CcUECQLEKhgJwBzOD8+QmJy5R24IS2YczhNtAYLZnv5AsF4IDYEJInIYolvr98hYPkIatotPUDCoihFSkI+skhtocD8gd1CZMoCSydsMXVCdjFr0DKzWaTfpkLldZmy2Y0WhoOUDMrQIBAqCoFoLGbFpUtCTMHHNlpwgA)